# Is making Software for a beer company permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, work

My company currently has given me the project which is making software for beer company for all the operation that done at production line for beer manufacturing and there packaging. If I work on this project then it will be haram.? Jazak allahu khairan

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a question similar to yours answered from a respected Sheikh.
Here is a quote:

> If you're building something that you know - certainly - will be used
>
> - primary - for prohibited purposes, such as selling weapons, gambling, liquor or pork products, then this is a prohibited act.
>
> God said: "Aid one another towards the common good and righteousness,
> and aid not one another towards vice and aggression."

Source: [Here](https://t.me/Qutooff/7841?embed=1&utm_source=thearchive.me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation 2 month back so I wrote to Shaikh:

I have an offer to work with **New York City  Department of Liquor Authority** as a software engineer!
In Islam, is it halal to work with such kind of departments?

And here was the answer:

> No, it's not allowed. Because of it issues permit of liquors. May
>   Allah provide you with something better.

See some hadeeths:

[Sahih al-Bukhari - Narrated `Aisha:](https://sunnah.com/urn/42211)

> When the last Verses of Surat-al-Baqara were revealed, the Prophet (ﷺ)
>   read them in the Mosque and prohibited the trade of alcoholic liquors.

Answer (score 0):

> My company currently has given me the project which is making software for beer company for all the operation that done at production line for beer manufacturing and there packaging. If I work on this project then it will be haram.?

You should let them know that this is considered haram in Islam; if they then say that, unfortunately, there is no other work, then it is mokru; if later, you find out that there was other work, but for whatever reasons, they did not assign you to that, I'd consider resigning as this is not a good company to work for - despite appearances.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answer in this link; go to 44:14 if it doesn't open up there:

https://youtu.be/NDCFhJ7YnKM?list=PLYZxc42QNctU5eNYDR02fdqWl900PQCH3&t=2654

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here.